# Navigate on several WinForms in a C# app

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio

I'm building a C# form application which contains several forms. (Login, Menu, Products, Users, Settings..etc).

This is the structure how the navigation happens.

[image]

Currently what I'm doing is hide the current form and create a new object of the next form and display it.

```
this.Hide();
Menu obj = new Menu();
obj.Show();
```

If I create objects for each visit to a form, there'll be lot of objects of that form. Right ?

Is this the correct way of doing it ?

And some of the navigation are bidirectional. There's a button on each form to go back.

So, what's the efficient way of closing the current form and go to next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better (this is subjective) flow would be:

Login and Menu are Forms that are considered top level.
When Login is complete, it is closed (not hidden), and Menu appears as the only form.

From Menu, you can pop-up Modal dialogs for the other screens. But only one of them can be open at a time. When they're closed, the user can control the Menu form again and open another screen.

Note, by Modal dialogs, they would appear on top of the Menu form, but Menu wouldn't be hidden. It is simply waiting for the modal to be closed before it regains control.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with windows that appear and disappear (regardless of whether they are *closed* or *hidden*) is that the end result may be disconcerting to the user.  They may feel that the program has quit and the link between prior and consecutive windows may not be easily understood.

### UserControls

Alternatively you may want to consider replacing your other windows with `UserControl`s.  This way you have a main window that consistantly stays open and you simply embed a `UserControl` representing the other pages into it.  Thus making it more obvious to the user that there is a notion of an consistent "app".

`Users`; `Products` and `Settings`, instead of deriving from `Form` would instead derive from `UserControl`.  To move from say `Users` to `Products`, simply remove `Users` from the `Controls` property; create a `Products` control and add it to `Controls` ensuring that it is set to `Dock.Fill`.

I see no reason why `Login` still can't remain a modal dialog though.

Comment: Is it a big deal to convert these windows to user controls ? (I'm kinda new to c#)

Comment: Not really.  In the designer, just select all the controls and paste them into the new `UserControl`.  You'll need to re-add any event-handling but again the body will be simply copy and paste. :)

Comment: OK, Will try that. :)